# Strange array return type

Tags: java, arrays, syntax, declaration

Has any one seen the array `[]` placed after the method signature like this?

```
public static String mySplit(String s)[] {
    return s.split(",");
}

public static void main(String... args) {
    String[] words = mySplit("a,b,c,d,e");
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(words));
}
```

prints

```
[a, b, c, d, e]
```

In the past, odd notations have been for "C" compatibility, but I wouldn't imagine someone writing this in C either.

Does anyone know why this is even allowed?

I am using Java 7 update 10, in case it matters.

This does the same thing in Java 6. http://ideone.com/91rZV1

---

BTW this doesn't compile, nor would I expect it to

```
public static <T> List mySplit(String s)<T> {
    return Collections.emptyList();
}
```

Comment: I could imagine a C programmer writing this horribility. C++ is known for its weird syntax when it comes to types, especially array types, especially when combined with function-pointer types.

Comment: Note that `inx x[10]` is exactly the same issue, except less exagerrated

Comment: The code even doesn't compile.

Comment: @RomanC Which one? The one marked as such?

Comment: @JanDvorak Perhaps he doesn't have `inx` defined. ;)

Comment: @JanDvorak The code from the above. non-static call from the static method.

Comment: @RomanC `mySplit` is static, so which one do you mean?

Comment: @JanDvorak Got it, that case matters to me, but not him. Arrays is changed in 1.7 probably to implement toString().

Comment: @RomanC I don't seea problem with one class having both `toString` and `static toString(String)`. However, you are right - didn't notice this call or find the method name suspicious.

Comment: @JanDvorak In 1.6 there's no method toString() in Arrays and it uses Object's one that is non-static

Comment: Java 6 b14 (early days) has Arrays.toString(Object[]) and it's Javadoc says "since 1.5" http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/Arrays.java#Arrays.toString%28java.lang.Object[]%29

Comment: I'm still running JDK 1.6.0_32 don't know why.

Comment: @RomanC Java 6 update 32 is an ok version. ;)

Comment: @PeterLawrey You're right I don't have any problem with it never. But Oracle stopped supporting it in the late of December last year.

Comment: When I learned Java, 'javap' did this by default. It always mystified me why (and made reading the output much trickier).

Answer (score 90, accepted):

> Does anyone know why this is even allowed?

In this case it's for backward compatibility with Java itself. From the [JLS section 8.4](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4):

> For compatibility with older versions of the Java SE platform, the declaration of a method that returns an array is allowed to place (some or all of) the empty bracket pairs that form the declaration of the array type after the formal parameter list. This is supported by the following obsolescent production, but should not be used in new code.

And yes, you should indeed regard it as an abomination which has no good purpose other than to shock other developers. Actually, you might be able to use it to win some money at parties by betting that it would compile, against folks who've never seen it...

Here's the kind of method which right-minded coders would expect to be invalid:

```
public String[] mwahahaha(String[] evil[])[] {
    return evil;
}
```

Comment: @nicholas.hauschild I am having a dinner with a crowd of Java developers on Thursday. That's got to almost count. ;)

Comment: @JonSkeet Better than `(String[]... evil)` ;)

Comment: @PeterLawrey why not `(String[]... evil[])`?

Comment: @PeterLawrey: I tried mixing both, but got: "legacy array notation not allowed on variable-arity parameter"

Comment: @JanDvorak: See my comment to Peter... it's sadly disallowed.

Comment: @JonSkeet Which one is the legacy one; `evil[]`?

Comment: Backwards compatibility sometimes goes way too far... Idle comment.

Comment: @fge Some deprecated methods have been deprecated for more than ten years. They should have a special deprecated which means new code doesn't compile, or doesn't find it. I would add StringBuffer to that list and it's not even deprecated ;)

Comment: @PeterLawrey No matter how much you wish there would, there is no reliable way to determine the age of some line of code.

Comment: @JanDvorak True but if you have an old copy (or in Oracle's case every old copy released) and the code is the same, you might assume it is at least as old as the code you have which is the same.

Comment: @PeterLawrey not just library code is legacy. You can't hold a whitelist of code that is allowed to use some method.

Comment: @JanDvorak Which rules out runtime checks unfortunately.

Comment: @PeterLawrey I oppose to the whole idea of whitelisting / blacklisting specific code. As if a simple overstrike in the IDE didn't suffice...

Comment: @JanDvorak Most developers are pretty good at ignoring static analysis & compiler warnings I find.

Comment: @PeterLawrey There's a difference between a "mere" yellow triangle in the left gutter and a solid black line across the whole method name. You can't easily miss the latter.

Comment: @JanDvorak In IntelliJ it has yellow across the whole code in question and can prevent checkin of code which fails static analysis...

Answer (score 20):

It's like

```
  String[] a;
```

is the same as

```
  String a[];
```

Same works for the syntax of method return types

```
  public static String mySplit(String s)[] {
```

is the same as

```
  public static String[] mySplit(String s) {
```

But I think I never saw the version you mentioned in productive code yet.

Comment: I don't think I've ever seen it either; should I, I'm posting to TDWTF

Answer (score 6):

I think its the same reason that the following variable declarations are both equivalent

```
String[] array
String array[]
```

this is a thing C developers do, so it was included to help them.

Comment: "this is a thing C developers do, so it was included to help them." <-- if you had litterature about this particular point, I'd like pointers, it could be a fun read! (especially since I _did_ C before and couldn't for the life of me understand the Java notation in the beginning)

Answer (score 4):

I believe it's just telling Java that the return type is an array of `Strings`, the same as declaring

```
static String[] mySplit(String s) {...
```

Similar to declaring variables:

```
String myStringArray[];
```

is equivalent to

```
String[] myStringArray;
```

Answer (score 4):

Good question; when I implemented a Java parser I remember getting really confused by the JLS grammar at this point.

To expand on John's answer, here's what's going on:

- this is called ["mixed notation"](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-10.html#jls-10.2) in the spec
- the [grammar](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-18.html) breaks type declarations into two pieces, each of which may have 0 or more `[]`s

There are (at least) 5 places where this matters:

- method type signatures
- local variable declarations
- field declarations
- formal parameters
- `for`-loops

Here's an excerpt from the grammar, focusing on method declarations:

```
MethodOrFieldDecl:
    Type Identifier MethodOrFieldRest

MethodOrFieldRest:  
    FieldDeclaratorsRest ;
    MethodDeclaratorRest

MethodDeclaratorRest:
    FormalParameters {[]} [throws QualifiedIdentifierList] (Block | ;)

Type:
    BasicType {[]}
    ReferenceType  {[]}
```

*(Warning: it's difficult to read the grammar because the square and curly brackets are sometimes literals and sometimes metacharacters.)*

This shows that `[]` can appear both under the `Type` rule, and as part of the `MethodDeclaratorRest` rule.  It is optional in both places.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is allowed,

same reason that:

```
String[] myArray;
```

is equivalent to

```
String myArray[];
```